# What's the function of each of the words in the following interrogative sentence: "Did you do your homework"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

What is the purpose of "Did"? and "you" after the word "did"? What does "Did" used in the beginning of a sentence usually mean?

Answer (score 2):

> Did you do your homework?

*You* is the subject.

The *do* here is a lexical/main verb, not to be confused with an auxiliary verb.  Hence, to form a question we need **do-support**, which is the *Did*.

> Do-support (or do-insertion), in English grammar, is the use of the auxiliary verb do, including its inflected forms does and did, to form negated clauses and questions as well as other constructions in which subject–auxiliary inversion is required.

Care to differentiate the functions of **do**, as highlighted here, and more explanations are found in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support).

> [T]he use of do as an auxiliary should be distinguished from the use of do as a normal lexical verb, as in They do their homework.

Comment: But what would it mean in terms of circumstances when being asked by a teacher, if they "did" their homework? Or someone were to ask "Did you take a shower"?, Where would this have to do with suggested circumstances?